# upload binary data or file from memory using python http post

Tags: python

I have seen the receipes for uploading files via [multipartform-data](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/146306-http-client-to-post-using-multipartform-data/) and [pycurl](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576422/). 
 Both methods seem to require a file on disk.  
 Can these recipes be modified to supply binary data from memory instead of from disk ? 
I guess I could just use a [xmlrpc server](http://docs.python.org/library/xmlrpclib.html#binary-objects) instead.
I wanted to get around having to encode and decode the binary data and send it raw...  
Do pycurl and mutlipartform-data work with raw data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a solution that works with the cherrypy file upload example: [urllib2-binary-upload.py](http://uthcode.sarovar.org/pythonsnippets.html)

Answer (score 2):

This (small) library will take a file descriptor, and will do the HTTP POST operation:  https://github.com/seisen/urllib2_file/

You can pass it a `StringIO` object (containing your in-memory data) as the file descriptor.

Comment: urllib2_file builds and passes its own tests.  But it fails with the cherrypy file upload sample http://docs.cherrypy.org/dev/progguide/files/uploading.html  Not sure if the problem is with the cherrypy sample or with urllib2_file.  I tried python test-upload.py -u http://www.myurl.com -f mytest.py -n myFile

Comment: Have you tried using urllib2_file to upload to another (non cherrypy) server to see if it works?

Answer (score 1):

Find something that cas work with a file handle. Then simply pass a StringIO object instead of a real file descriptor.

Comment: unfortunately both recipes take a filename not a file descriptor.

Comment: The last time I've looked for something there was a patch for urllib2 which allowed passing a file descriptor in the POST data list

Answer (score 1):

I met similar issue today, after tried both and pycurl and multipart/form-data, I decide to read python httplib/urllib2 source code to find out, I did get one comparably good solution:

1. set Content-Length header(of the file) before doing post
2. pass a opened file when doing post

Here is the code:

```
import urllib2, os
image_path = "png\\01.png"
url = 'http://xx.oo.com/webserviceapi/postfile/'
length = os.path.getsize(image_path)
png_data = open(image_path, "rb")
request = urllib2.Request(url, data=png_data)
request.add_header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache')
request.add_header('Content-Length', '%d' % length)
request.add_header('Content-Type', 'image/png')
res = urllib2.urlopen(request).read().strip()
return res
```

see my blog post: http://www.2maomao.com/blog/python-http-post-a-binary-file-using-urllib2/

Comment: Is this code snippet licensed somehow? Can I use it in my GPL code (of course with your attribution)?

Comment: @Turion please go ahead to use it in your code, I wrote this script for my own tool only.

Answer (score 1):

Following python code works reliable on 2.6.x. The input data is of type str.
Note that the server that receives the data has to loop to read all the data as the large 
data sizes will be chunked. Also attached java code snippet to read the chunked data.

```
def post(self, url, data):
    self.curl = pycurl.Curl()
    self.response_headers = StringIO.StringIO()
    self.response_body = io.BytesIO()
    self.curl.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, self.response_body.write)
    self.curl.setopt(pycurl.HEADERFUNCTION, self.response_headers.write)
    self.curl.setopt(pycurl.FOLLOWLOCATION, 1)
    self.curl.setopt(pycurl.MAXREDIRS, 5)
    self.curl.setopt(pycurl.TIMEOUT, 60)
    self.curl.setopt(pycurl.ENCODING,"deflate, gzip")
    self.curl.setopt(pycurl.URL, url)
    self.curl.setopt(pycurl.VERBOSE, 1)
    self.curl.setopt(pycurl.POST,1)
    self.curl.setopt(pycurl.POSTFIELDS,data)
    self.curl.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER, [ "Content-Type: octate-stream" ])
    self.curl.setopt(pycurl.POSTFIELDSIZE, len(data))
    self.curl.perform()
    return url, self.curl.getinfo(pycurl.RESPONSE_CODE),self.response_headers.getvalue(), self.response_body.getvalue()
```

Java code for the servlet engine:

```
int postSize = Integer.parseInt(req.getHeader("Content-Length"));
results = new byte[postSize];
int read = 0;
while(read < postSize) {
      int n = req.getInputStream().read(results);
      if (n < 0) break;
      read += n;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import io         # Part of core Python
import requests   # Install via: 'pip install requests'

# Get the data in bytes. I got it via:
#   with open("smile.gif", "rb") as fp: data = fp.read()
data = b"GIF89a\x12\x00\x12\x00\x80\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00!\xf9\x04\x01\n\x00\x01\x00,\x00\x00\x00\x00\x12\x00\x12\x00\x00\x024\x84\x8f\x10\xcba\x8b\xd8ko6\xa8\xa0\xb3Wo\xde9X\x18*\x15x\x99\xd9'\xad\x1b\xe5r(9\xd2\x9d\xe9\xdd\xde\xea\xe6<,\xa3\xd8r\xb5[\xaf\x05\x1b~\x8e\x81\x02\x00;"

# Hookbin is similar to requestbin - just a neat little service
# which helps you to understand which queries are sent
url = 'https://hookb.in/je2rEl733Yt9dlMMdodB'

in_memory_file = io.BytesIO(data)
response = requests.post(url, files=(("smile.gif", in_memory_file),))
```